# adb error: device unauthorized when running commands with python subprocess

Tags: python, android

I can connect and run commands with adb normally without errors directly from my terminal, but when I run a python script that uses commands with `subprocess.check_output/call` etc, I always get the following error:

```
 error: device unauthorized
 This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' is that seems wrong.
```

But when I check with `adb devices` I can see that the device is actually authorized.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try running with `sudo`

Comment: tried, same error